# copy paste files using CMD

Tags: cmd, copy, xcopy

I want to accomplish the following: copy File A from Directory A to Directory B but File A already exist in Directory B and i don't want to overwrite it, simply put the new file in Directory B with a (1) or something so i'll know the difference. i can't manually name the file in the script as i plan to make it a batch file and run it every few hours therefore resulting in the same file existing with different names. IE. File A, File A(1), File A(2) so on and so on. please help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use Xcopy command with parameter /D

```
 C:\> xcopy D:\source_dest E:\target_dest /E /D
```

/E parameter make that it copy files with subfolders

/D parameter make that it copy files without overwrite

if want more help inform me .if it works vote up

Comment: when i press enter it says: Cannot perform a cyclic copy

Comment: i googled the error it says you cannot paste into a same directory so i tried copying form my Z to C and it asked me if i wanted to overwrite, i said no, and now it is kind of stuck. nothing happends, i tried few times now

Answer (score 0):

A cyclic copy refers to the situation where the source directory
    contains the destination directory.  Since the destination directory
    is part of the source, the copying process eventually starts copying
    the destination directory to a deeper portion of the destination.
    This process will continue until, of course, the finite disk space
    eventually runs out.

```
To avoid this condition but to achieve the objective, one can
specify a temporary destination which is on another volume (e.g.,
D:\temp\) and later copy the temporary destination to the final
destination, and delete the temporary directory at the end.
```

Comment: so i tried copying form my Z to C and it asked me if i wanted to overwrite, i said no, and now it is kind of stuck. nothing happends, i tried few times now

Answer (score 0):

just check file exist before run xcopy command then run copy command

```
if NOT  EXIST c:\directory B\File A ( xcopy c:\Directory A\File A c:\Directory B )
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The following is made for folders but you can modify it for files.

Makes a backup of existed folder directory (and all contents in it) with new increase number in folder name  [like TEST(1)... TEST(2)... folder].

The first part `:Start` will set the `%PathFolder%` variable with path to folder name (`%userprofile%\Desktop\TEST`) and then will search if exist. If NOT exists, will create it (`xcopy`), else, If exist, will directing the `%PathFolder%` variable to `:Search` label (for-)loop section for further handling...

Tip: Can be used `%1` variable to set PathFolder `set "PathFolder=%1"` so it will work when you Drag-n-Drop a folder on this current saved batch file.

The second part `:Search` will search in the `%PathFolder%` variable (`%userprofile%\Desktop\TEST`) and will make a COPY of "TEST" folder (and all contents in it) with an increase number added in parenthesis at the end of folder name [like TEST(1)]. If already exist TEST(1) then will copy TEST folder as TEST(2) ... or TEST(3) ... and so on.

```
::Make a backup of existed folder directory (and all contents in it) with new increase number in folder name.

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "IncrNum=1"

:Start

::The following will set the "%PathFolder%" variable with path to folder name (%userprofile%\Desktop\TEST) and then will search if exist. If NOT exists, will create it (xcopy), else, If exist, will directing the "%PathFolder%" variable to :Search label (for-)loop section for further handling...
::Tip: Can be used %1 instead of %userprofile%\Desktop\TEST in [set "PathFolder=..."] line so it will work when you Drag-n-Drop a folder on this current saved batch file.
set "PathFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\TEST"
if NOT exist "%PathFolder%" (
    xcopy %PathFolder% %PathFolder% /i /y
    exit /b
    ) else (
    goto :Search
    )
exit /b

:Search

::The following will search in the "%PathFolder%" variable (%userprofile%\Desktop\TEST) and will make a COPY of "TEST" folder (and all contents in it) with an increase number added in parenthesis at the end of folder name [like TEST(1)]. If alredy exist TEST(1) then will copy TEST folder as TEST(2) ... or TEST(3) ... and so on.

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "%PathFolder%*"') do (
    if exist %%G^(%IncrNum%^) (
        echo At "%%~dpG" a folder "%%~nG(%IncrNum%)" alredy existed.
        set /a IncrNum+=1
        goto :Search
        ) else (
            echo.
            echo.
            echo  The "%%~nG" folder and all contents in it
            echo  will be copied now as "%%G(%IncrNum%)".
            echo.
            pause
            xcopy %%G %%G^(%IncrNum%^) /i /y
            exit /b
            )
)

:EndBatch
set "PathFolder="
pause
exit
```